# Attendance Data in the desire2learn Valence API

Tags: desire2learn

Is there a way to access Attendance Data through the Valence API? I've been through it and have seen no mention of it. Am I missing something, or is just not there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the Valence API does not expose access to Attendance functionality (attendance schemes, registers, sessions, or attendance data). If D2L clients want to register a request to add support for Attendance functionality, then they can use the [D2L Product Ideas Exchange](https://community.brightspace.com/sharedresources/glossary/library/product_ideas_exchange_pie) to open register (and vote for) the idea.

Comment: How often are feature requests like this from users added to Valence?

Comment: The Valence API is still young; in general, the intention is to give feature requests priority from a variety of factors -- the number of clients requesting them, alignment with existing work on the dev team's roadmap, and so forth.

Comment: Viktor, has there been any movement towards adding Attendance data access into Valence?

Comment: Hey Johnny -- D2L doesn't use the system we used for tracking these things any more; I will edit the answer to account for this. It's also possible this issue didn't get transferred from the old system to the new one. I will ensure that it gets logged in the new system.